# xdotool can't detect headless firefox on redhat No GUI

Tags: redhat, xdotool

Xdotool can't control a headless instance of firefox Started with  ( -- headless, - marionette) args.

i have tried :
xdotool search firefox

result :
Defaulting to search window name, class, and class name.

```
# ps -ef |grep firefox
root     26978 26956 80 13:07 ?        00:00:04 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -marionette -devtools -headless -foreground -no-remote -profile /tmp/rust_mozprofile.4opdLmN4k4Kh
root     27087 26978  9 13:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -intPrefs 42:0|44:0|74:0|236:1| -boolPrefs 5:0|61:1|81:1|235:0|277:0|280:0|303:0| -stringPrefs 289:36;891fda99-943a-4201-9d2d-10d20e19cbe4| -schedulerPrefs 0001,2 -greomni /usr/lib64/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib64/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /usr/lib64/firefox/browser 26978 tab
root     27225 26978 20 13:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -intPrefs 42:0|44:0|74:0|236:1| -boolPrefs 5:0|61:1|81:1|235:0|277:0|280:0|303:0| -stringPrefs 289:36;891fda99-943a-4201-9d2d-10d20e19cbe4| -schedulerPrefs 0001,2 -greomni /usr/lib64/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib64/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /usr/lib64/firefox/browser 26978 tab
root     28163  6735  0 12:13 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/xvfb-run -s :99 -auth /tmp/xvfb.auth -ac -screen 0 1920x1080x24 firefox -headless -marionette
root     28205 28163  0 12:13 pts/0    00:00:08 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -headless -marionette
root     29630  6735  0 13:08 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto firefox
root     29773 28205  0 12:14 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -boolPrefs 303:0| -stringPrefs 289:36;65ada97a-bd97-4caa-8ca0-591ccabedcf1| -schedulerPrefs 0001,2 -greomni /usr/lib64/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib64/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /usr/lib64/firefox/browser 28205 tab
# xdotool search firefox
Defaulting to search window name, class, and classname
```

as you see many instances running but can't find any window

also tried:

```
# xdotool getactivewindow
Your windowmanager claims not to support _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW, so the attempt to query the active window aborted.
xdo_get_active_window reported an error
```